SQL Query to Retrieve Latest Values from Multiple Columns
i have a table a with the following columns :
a.client_id, a.viral_load_value, a.date_vl_sample_collected, a.encounter_datetime

And another table b with the following column :
b.client_id, b.art_start_date

And another table c with the following column :
c.client_id, c.eac_session

And another table d with the following column :
 mp.client_id, mp.age

I am trying to retrieve columns with the following conditions as long as the data lies less than the a.encounter_datetime:

d.age > 19 years old, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, b.art_start_date, NOW()) >= 6 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.date_vl_sample_collected, NOW()) >= 6

d.age > 19 years old and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.date_vl_sample_collected, NOW()) >= 6

c.eac_session = 'Third EAC Session' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.date_vl_sample_collected, NOW()) >= 1


a.encounter_datetime is like a visit date
Considerations , d.age , a.viral_load_value and a.date_vl_sample_collected should be the latest , and lie less than the a.encounter_datetime.
The a.date_vl_sample_collected should be the latest, if subsequent ones are null, consider the latest.
This is my current query :
    SELECT 
        a.client_id, 
        d.age,
        a.viral_load_value,
        a.date_vl_sample_collected, 
        a.encounter_datetime, 
        a.client_pregnant,
        b.art_start_date, 
        c.eac_session,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.client_id ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN a.date_vl_sample_collected IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
            a.date_vl_sample_collected DESC, 
            a.encounter_datetime DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
         test_dump.a
    JOIN test_dump.d ON a.client_id = d.client_id
    LEFT JOIN test_dump.b ON a.client_id = b.client_id
    LEFT JOIN test_dump.c ON a.client_id = c.client_id
    JOIN MaxSampleDate ms ON a.client_id = ms.client_id 
        AND a.date_vl_sample_collected = ms.max_date_vl_sample_collected
    WHERE 
        a.encounter_datetime <= '2024-10-02' -- specify your endDate here
        AND (a.date_vl_sample_collected IS NULL OR a.encounter_datetime >= a.date_vl_sample_collected)
        AND (
            (d.age > 19 
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, b.art_start_date, NOW()) >= 6 
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.date_vl_sample_collected, "2024-10-02") >= 6)
                AND a.viral_load_value < 1000 
            OR
            (d.age <= 18 
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.date_vl_sample_collected, "2024-10-02") >= 6)
            OR 
            (c.eac_session = 'Third EAC Session' 
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.date_vl_sample_collected, "2024-10-02") >= 1)
            OR
            (a.client_pregnant = 'Yes' 
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, b.art_start_date, "2024-10-02") < 1
            )
            OR
            (a.client_pregnant = 'Yes' 
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, b.art_start_date, "2024-10-01") >= 6
               AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, a.date_vl_sample_collected, "2024-10-01") > 3
            )
        )
)
 SELECT * FROM RankedData;

The query :
SELECT client_id, MAX(date_vl_sample_collected) AS max_date_vl_sample_collected FROM a WHERE date_vl_sample_collected < '2024-10-02' GROUP BY client_id

returns what i want, but when i add the rest of the conditions, the results are quite inconsistent. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
Here is my sandbox with data

Make it easy to help you, simplify your example. Provide a complete (and consistent) [mcve]. A fiddle (e.g https://dbfiddle.uk) would be great to

And format your SQL properly. That wall of SQL is more or less unreadable.

Which MySQL version are you using?

@jarlh i am using mysql 8

Your first query has a group by but no aggregate functions..this is not a good thing.

You have 2 close votes already. One more and your question will be gone. You'd better hurry up and follow the improvement suggestions you've already got.

Use window functions, FIRST_VALUE() when you need in the most last value for separate column, and ROW_NUMBER() in CTE when you need in the most last row. Max date in CTE/subquery then join is too ancient method.

@jarlh i have added a fiddle link

You say you are on v8 but created a fiddle in v5.7 - this bothers me , please publish the result of select version();

If you step back a bit do you see how jargon laden the question is? And how long it will take for someone to make sense of this mass of data (most of it irrelevant) that does not have your familiarity with the data? For a quicker response I suggest you slim down your data to only include the columns you need.

@P.Salmon let me slim it

@P.Salmon  i have updated my question and sandbox

code fragment AND ... AND a.viral_load_value < 1000 or a.viral_load_value is null will be AND ... (AND a.viral_load_value < 1000 or a.viral_load_value is null)? Priority of OR and AND is different.
